# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setAttribute: Non-serializable attribute

Tags: java

I have inherited some code and am getting an error when I try to run it. The error is below:

```
10:08:32,093 ERROR [MyServlet]:260 - Servlet.service() for servlet MyServlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setAttribute: Non-serializable attribute
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.setAttribute(StandardSession.java:1270)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.setAttribute(StandardSession.java:1248)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.setAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:130)
at uk.co.my.servlet.MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:121)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at com.my.ddi.security.SecurityContextServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextServletFilter.java:55)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:835)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:640)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1286)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I imagine that the main problem is where it is hitting my code *at uk.co.my.servlet.MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:172)*. Line 121 of  MyServlet is 
session.setAttribute("LISTENER", myListener);

This myListener object is from the following class:

```
public class myListener {
    static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TerminationListener.class.getName());
    private boolean shouldCancel = false;
```

How would I go about getting rid of this error? Would I need to use the transient keyword?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want an instance of `myListener` to be placed in a session, you need to make it serializable. That *might* involve making some fields transient, but then those fields won't be saved in the session. You'll also need to make the class implement `Serializable`.

I suggest you look at the [documentation for Serializable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), which goes into a fair amount of detail about serialization.