# Memcache or Persistent Datastore [GAEJ]

Tags: java, google-app-engine, database-design

I want to store a name-value pair collection that would be persistent over a user web session that would on an average last for 30 mins. This data makes no sense to me after the session.

I had 2 options to go for; Memcache and the GAE datastore. The only thing important to me would be the retrieval speed.

Could you suggest me which one to go for?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the memcache if retrieval speed is *really* the only thing important to you. If not losing your data is also important, use the datastore.

Comment: Okay. Ideally, what is the maximum cache size allowed before it's deleted by GAE?

Comment: There is no published maximum allowed size. Your data might disappear from the cache at any time; it should never be relied upon to act as anything but a volatile cache.

Comment: Max size of a cached value is 1MB (as of today).  See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview

Comment: @jeffrey_t_b: right, a single value in the cache can't be larger than 1MB, but there's no set limit on how much you can stick in the memcache before things start getting evicted; if there's unusually high usage at a given moment everyone's data can get evicted faster than usual, or a server can die horribly and lose all of the data on it at any time.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a [session support](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Enabling_Sessions) in GAE, that give you exactly what you need:

1. GAE sessions are tied to user session, i.e. they handle the session via cookies in user's browser.
2. Data saved to session is saved to both memcache and datastore, so it's both fast and truly persistent.

You can simply save data to session via:

```
request.getSession(boolean create).setAttribute(key, object)
```

Note that object [must implement `Serializable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790705/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-setattribute-non-serializable-attribute).